# How to select whole column (e.g. B) except single cell in the middle (e.g. B43) for formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to do a countifs formula, but I want the range to be whole column B except B43. What should I put in the formula?

Comment: Do two COUNTIFs (one through B42 and one from B44 to end of range) and then add the results.

Comment: @chuff is correct, but there may be a simpler way if B43 has a specific trait that makes you want to exclude it (it's a formula, it's blank, etc). If the solution doesn't work for you, include in your post what your criteria is and what formulas you've tried

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this:

- Use two `COUNTIFS` formulas, with the first using the criterion range `B1:B42` (and any further criterion ranges of the same length) and the second using the criterion range `B44:B100` (and the other criteria), where the 100 in B100 shoud be changed to the last row of your data range. You then add the two `COUNTIFS`.
- The second way also uses two `COUNTIFS`. The first would use the entire column `B:B` and the second would use only `B43`. You would then subtract the `B43` `COUNTIFS` from the `B:B` `COUNTIFS`.

I would tend to prefer the first way over the second.